# Will having three proxies like below tunnel similar to tor?

Tags: vpn

If I connect to a VPN on Windows, then I open a virtual machine and connect to a second VPN, and then I go to my browser in the Virtual Machine and connect to a proxy.

Will the connection now have 3 layers like this, *VPN > VPN 2 > Proxy*,
or do I need to do something else to get that configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the VM host machine configuration. If your VM has raw access to your host machines network adapter connection it may not work as intended. You can test your idea by first connecting the host operating system (windows) to the first VPN. Then run your browser on the VM and go to "canyouseeme.org". Is the IP that this website is showing you the VPN IP number from your host operating system? Or is it your actual WAN IP number? If it's your VPN IP number, you then connect the VM to the second VPN connection and redo the test from the first step. If not you have configuration issues on the host machine. does canyouseeme.org show you the WAN IP, VM host VPN IP, or the second VPN connections IP? In theory this can work, it's going to add an incredible amount of latency to the machine that's connecting through it.  you can add an extra layer of security by connecting to a single VPN then using the Tor network through it BTW.

Answer (score 0):

technically yes that should work, although depending on what you are using your proxies and VPNs for, as well as which proxies and VPNs you chose, it may or may not protect you the way you expect. If you are using the same VPN service for all three, then it would effectively work as a single VPN.

So... Whatcha planning on pirating?

EDIT: as a response to the second comment, that would honestly be the best method for most things. Use a single VPN and then a tor browser or tor similar browser that hides your browsing activities would be a great plan. It would be just as safe, and just as unlikely to be gotten through. If you really want as much security as possible, then go ahead and do your plan, follow his instructions to set it all up so that you get the VPNs in order, and the latency to a maximum and then use tor or something like it under all that. Youll never be found.. unless youre hacking the government... They always know.